# Ubuntu Customized Live CD Fails to run Display Manager

Tags: 15.04, live-cd, customization

I was testing a customization on an Ubuntu 15.04 Live CD and I got this error,

```
 Stopping User Manager for UID 999... [ OK ] Stopped User Manager for UID 999. [ OK ] Removed user-999.slice. [ OK ] Started Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit [ OK ] Started Getty on tty1. Starting Getty on tty1... [ OK ] Reached target Login Prompts. [ OK ] Reached target Multi-User System. [ OK ] Reached target Graphical Interface. Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes... [ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes
```

I did what the guide said and it still failed. It boots up, gets a black screen and then goes back to the splash. I followed the instructions from [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization). What did I do wrong? I followed customization limits, so I shouldn't see the error.

Comment: What did you customize ? Can you provide the entire error message ?

Comment: Yes I can, it is: Stopping User Manager for UID 999... [   OK   ] Stopped User Manager for UID 999. [    OK   ] Removed user-999.slice.  [    OK   ] Started Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit [    OK   ] Started Getty on tty1. Starting Getty on tty1... [   OK    ] Reached target Login Prompts. [    OK   ] Reached target Multi-User System. [   OK  ] Reached target Graphical Interface. Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...  [    OK   ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes. And then the computer freezes. I followed the guide. I'm using GDM on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see from "official LiveCDCustomization" at section "Customization limits";

seem that

users with an UID == 999

it not to like ubuntu

Rif: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: I did, but I still got an error